# Is a spectral projection strongly/norm continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Given a bounded self-adjoint operator $H$ and a number $\mu$, consider the spectral projection $P_\mu$ onto the set $\{x|x\leq\mu\}$. I want to check if the map $\mu\mapsto P_\mu$ is strongly/norm continuous but I actually have no clue what a rigorous definition of a strongly/norm continuous map is. What would be the best way to approach this?

Any help/reference is welcome.

Comment: You need to prove that the map $$\mu\mapsto P_\mu(x)$$ is continuous for every $x\in H$.

Comment: Yes, but what does it mean to be continuous within the strong operator topology? @Ruy

Comment: My comment above points to a quick and dirty method for determining whether or not $P$ is continuous in the strong
operator topology.  However, in order to fully answer your question it would be good to know how much you already know
about Topology.  Do you know what a topological space is?  Do you know what is a continuous map between topological
spaces?  Do you know what is the definition of the strong operator topology?

Comment: I know more or less all of the above except for the strong operator topology, that is where I lose touch. I think, once I have some sort of rigorous definition of what it means for a map to be strongly continuous, I'll be able to figure the rest out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so we are talking about a map
$$
  P:\mu \in {\mathbb R}\mapsto P_\mu \in B(H)
  $$
from the topological space ${\mathbb R}$ (with its usual topology)  into the space $B(H)$ of all
operators on the Hilbert space $H$.

Strongly continuous simply means that the map is continuous when $B(H)$ is seen as a topological space equipped  with
the *misterious strong-operator-topology (SOT)* (more later).

According to the standard definition, $P$ is continuous at a point $\mu _0\in {\mathbb R}$ iff, for every open set $U$ (relative to the SOT)
containing $P_{\mu _0}$, there is an open subset  $V\subseteq {\mathbb R}$ cointaining $\mu _0$,  such that
$$
  P_V = \{P_\mu : \mu \in V\} \subseteq U.
  $$

Everything should be clear by now,  except for what the heck is an open set relative to the SOT!

Before answering that, let me say that
one of the most common methods to introduce a topology on a set $X$ (in our case $X=B(H)$) is via a *generating
collection of sets* which we later want to be open.

So, suppose we are given a set $X$,  and a collection $\mathscr U$ of subsets of $X$.

Should we want to define a topology $\mathscr T$ on $X$,
relative to which the members of $\mathscr U$ are open, in other words, such that
$$
  \mathscr U\subseteq \mathscr T,
  $$
we are forced to accept that any set of the form
$$
  U_1\cap U_2\cap \ldots \cap U_n,
  \tag 1
  $$
where the $U_i\in \mathscr U$, is also open.

So we make a first  attempt (it will not work) to define $\mathscr T$ to be the
collection of all finite intersections of sets from $\mathscr U$, namely all sets of the form (1).

The trouble is that $\mathscr T$ is not a topology: even though it is closed under finite intersections,  it is not
closed under unions.

In other words, we are also forced to accept as open,   any set of the form
$$
  \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}V_\alpha ,
  \tag 2
  $$
where each $V_\alpha $ is of the form (1).

We then define (this time it will work) $\mathscr T$ to be the collection of all (beware of the tongue-twister)
*arbitrary unions of finite intersections of members of $\mathscr U$*, namely, sets of the form (2).

It may now be shown that $\mathscr T$ is a topology, and in  fact the smaller topology relative to which   $\mathscr
U\subseteq \mathscr T$.  For that reason $\mathscr T$ is also known as the topology generated by $\mathscr U$.

This said, the SOT is the topology on $B(H)$ generated by the collection $\mathscr U$ of all subsets of the form
$$
  U_{u, v, r} = \big \{T\in  B(H): \|T(u)-v\|<r\big \},
  $$
as $u$ and $v$ range in $H$, and $r$ range in $(0,\infty )$.

**Exercise**.  Let $X$ be a topological space and let $T:X\to B(H)$ be a function.  Prove that $f$ is SOT-continuous at a
point $x_0\in X$,  iff,
for every $u\in H$,  the function
$$
  x\in X\mapsto T(x)(u)\in H
  $$
is continuous at $x_0$ (where $H$ has its usual topology defined by the norm).

Comment: This is amazing, thank you!